# How to set user to relogin to site with IIS 6 authenication

Tags: iis

We have an internal website that is protected with IIS authentication against a domain. When the user is successful with id and password, the site will go out via REST with an api key and get a url back from the vendor. They are then redirected to that vendor's url with .net redirect.

However I noticed the user is not prompted to enter a password again if they visit the our site. What can we do?

Comment: The browser's caching the credentials...you don't want that?

Comment: No because some computers might be shared. Ok I'm reading about basic authenication now...